# How to group by hourly or 15 minutes using postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I tried to group by hourly, but failed.

Here my query

```
self
    .where{ name =~ 'MemoryInfo' }
    .where{ sony_alarm_test_id.eq(test_id)}
    .group("DATE_PART('hour', utc_time )").count
```

The error message

```
D, [2014-06-27T15:34:39.713265 #26124] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE_PART('hour', utc_time ) AS date_part_hour_utc_time FROM "sony_alarm_logs" WHERE "sony_alarm_logs"."sony_alarm_test_id" = 1 AND "sony_alarm_logs"."name" ILIKE 'MemoryInfo' GROUP BY DATE_PART('hour', utc_time ) ORDER BY utc_time
E, [2014-06-27T15:34:39.713421 #26124] ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function date_part(unknown, double precision) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE_PART('hour', utc_time ) A...
```

Data

```
+-------+------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id    | name       | utc_time         | sony_alarm_test_id | brief_content                                          |
+-------+------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 25989 | MemoryInfo | 1403512193.57157 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150172", "shared"=>"6400"} |
| 25990 | MemoryInfo | 1403512224.60379 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150136", "shared"=>"6436"} |
| 25991 | MemoryInfo | 1403512255.63598 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 25992 | MemoryInfo | 1403512286.66835 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 25993 | MemoryInfo | 1403512317.70055 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150136", "shared"=>"6436"} |
| 25994 | MemoryInfo | 1403512348.73276 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150136", "shared"=>"6436"} |
| 25995 | MemoryInfo | 1403512379.76492 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 25996 | MemoryInfo | 1403512410.7972  | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150252", "shared"=>"6320"} |
| 25997 | MemoryInfo | 1403512441.82937 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 25998 | MemoryInfo | 1403512472.86155 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150224", "shared"=>"6348"} |
| 25999 | MemoryInfo | 1403512503.89374 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 26000 | MemoryInfo | 1403512534.92593 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 26001 | MemoryInfo | 1403512565.95812 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 26002 | MemoryInfo | 1403512596.99028 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
| 26003 | MemoryInfo | 1403512628.02261 | 5                  | {"used"=>"156572", "free"=>"150144", "shared"=>"6428"} |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function `date_part(unknown, double precision)`. Documentation for `date_part` is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) - it can accept `timestamp` or `interval`. Column `utc_time` is not `timestamp`.

You will need to use `to_timestamp()` function in your query ([docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)), something like:

```
self
    .where{ name =~ 'MemoryInfo' }
    .where{ sony_alarm_test_id.eq(test_id)}
    .group("DATE_PART('hour', to_timestamp(utc_time) )").count
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `utc_time` column is `double precision`. All [date/time functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) works on `timestamp[tz]`, `date` and `time[tz]` types.

You can convert your `double precision` fields to `timestamp` using the function `to_timestamp(double precision)` -- assuming `utc_time` counts seconds (and not milliseconds) from the unix epoch.